# ons-pull-hookを使った際のTypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nullのエラーについて

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

ons-pull-hookを実装したページでTypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nullのエラーが出ます。

ons-pull-hookを実装したページからpushPageで画面遷移し、
popPageで元のページへ戻り、もう一度pushPageで画面遷移すると、下記のようなエラーが出ます。

いろいろ試し上記の原因に辿り着いた所存です。
類似質問がないか確認しましたが見つからず、改善方法がわからずにいるのですが、どうしたらよいでしょうか？
動作自体に不便はないものの、エラーは吐き出され続けます。

ご回答いただけますと幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at Class._getState (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1462:11366)
at Class.getCurrentState (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1462:11432)
at Object.fn [as get] (eval at compile (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1455:15219), <anonymous>:4:254)
at Scope.$digest (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1453:6683)
at Scope.$apply (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1453:9117)
at HTMLSpanElement.listener (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1464:27782)
at HTMLSpanElement.eventHandler (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1450:138)
www/components/loader.js:1452 SOL26TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at Class._getState (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1462:11366)
at Class.getCurrentState (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1462:11432)
at Object.fn [as get] (eval at compile (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1455:15219), <anonymous>:4:254)
at Scope.$digest (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1453:6683)
at Scope.$apply (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1453:9117)
at HTMLSpanElement.listener (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1464:27782)
at HTMLSpanElement.eventHandler (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/57cd1101fd17349b08b593ce/www/components/loader.js:1450:138)
```